Transfering data from bigquery to bigquery using cloud run
How to transfer data from one bigquery project to another bigquery project using gcp cloud run

A simple request, an export to GCS and a load from GCS, BigQuery data transfer, dataset copy,... Many way to achieve it, pick the right one for you

Hi @aru, there are many ways to transfer data.Could you follow these link1 andlink2.Please let me know if these helps you.
